# Divs/text moving when i zoom in and zoom out on my webpage (html and css)

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding world. I have problem with my webpage, on 100% zoom on browser it's everything okay, but when I zoom in 150% or Zoom out scale everything will be messed. How can i fix everything to be on the same size when somebody zoom in and zoom out? Thank you in advance.

here some picture to understand u
[on 100% zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE4Kf.png)
[when i zoom out on my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSY5H.png)

Comment: Take a look at [how to create responsive webpages?](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Comment: i also use this tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> but its not working.. @MadyDaby

Comment: We need code samples. are you using `position: absolute`? flexbox?

Comment: Yes i used position: absolute..